# AutoMapper utilizing HasDefaultValueSql

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-core-2.2

In my Entity Framework Core 2.2 API project, I've built out the context. As it represents data from my database, I get entries like -

```
entity.Property(e => e.Active)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");
```

where `Active` is required with a default value of 1.

I am also mapping entities using AutoMapper.

My MappingEntity class -

```
public class MappingEntity : Profile
{
    public MappingEntity()
    {
        CreateMap<MemberUpdate, Member>();
    }
}
```

which will map the ViewModel `MemberUpdate` to my database object `Member`

I seem to be losing the default value within my controller -

```
public ActionResult Account(int id, [FromBody]MemberUpdate updatedMember)
{
    Member member = _memberRepository.GetById(id);
    //HERE MY MEMBER OBJECT IS CORRECT AND `ACTIVE` HAS IT'S DEFAULT VALUE

    member = _mapper.Map<Member>(updatedMember);
    //HERE MY MEMBER OBJECT IS INCORRECT AND THE ACTIVE FIELD DOES NOT SHOW THE DEFAULT VALUE

    //proceed to save back to the database
}
```

Is there an AutoMapper setting to preserve the default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoMapper can't retain your default value because it does not even know that it exists.

The `.HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");` is a setting that EntityFramework uses when **it** constructs the object, but in this case AutoMapper is constructing the object, so that information is lost.

What you *could* do however, is apply some custom logic to your mapping to add the default value in afterwards. It would look something like the following:

```
CreateMap<MemberUpdate, Member>()
    .AfterMap((memberUpdate, member) =>
         member.Active = memberUpdate.Active == default(int) ? 1 : memberUpdate.Active);
```

This simply does the default mapping between `Member` and `MemberUpdate` and then *afterwards* assigns the default value that you want for `Member`.

Alternatively, you could change your model to have the default value inside of it, rather than doing that assignment externally like:

```
public int Active { get; } = 1;
```

Though I doubt that option will be of use to you since you want EF to handle that for you. I would suggest stripping out the hard-coded `1` into a constant somewhere and then using that constant in your AutoMapper mapping and in the EF setting.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I may not have been clear. Does that mapping force the value after mapping? What if the incoming viewmodel sets it to something different?

Comment: Without seeing your models I had to unfortunately make a couple of assumptions. One of those was that your incoming model did not actually have such a property, but it seems I was wrong about that. Can you tell me what the expected behaviour is when the incoming viewmodel **does** have a value vs when it **doesn't**?

Comment: When the incoming model has that property, map it. If that property has not been set on the incoming model, use the database default

Comment: Okay I've just edited the mapping code in my post to handle that use case. Hope it helps!